# "expect_failure" attributes for bazel rules

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I want to define an "expect_failure" boolean attribute for a bazel rule set that I'm devising, so I can properly write tests for my tool chain.  However:

```
ERROR: /blah/blah.bzl:7:26: cannot add attribute: There is already a built-in attribute 'expect_failure' which cannot be overridden.
```

I can't find documentation for this "built-in attribute" anywhere.  When I attempt to make use of this built in attribute, I find that it is of type "string" rather than "bool" which maybe implies some nuance to its implementation.  When I attempt to naively use it by defining "expect_failure" to be the string "True", I see an unexpected error message:

```
ERROR: /blah/blah/BUILD:159:21: in _verilog_test rule //blah/blah:blah-test: Expected failure not found: True
```

Can anyone illuminate correct use of the built-in "expect_failure" attribute for me?

Comment: I took a peek at the bazel source code and it looks like the "expect_failure" attribute might only be usable for analysis tests.  It'd be a shame if this was true...

Answer (score 1):

`expect_failure` is use for analysis test framework. It depends on `analysistest`, and use to verify that a rule fails given certain inputs or in certain state.

Here is the [docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/testing.html#failure-testing)